# Set allowed value of a list field depending on the URL

Tags: entities

In the list field php code I want to set the value of a field:

1. first do a call to parse the URL.
2. take the [3] element (`nid` of the organic group) and use it to do a call to the db to get the node type for that `nid`.
3. set the value of the field depending on the node type.

I had all this working in D6, now have to redo for D7.  Not having any luck getting it working yet.

---

```
function custom_pathnoder() {
    $pathnoder = array();
    $pathnoder = check_plain(drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
    $pathnoder = explode('/', $pathnoder);
  return $pathnoder;
}

$node = menu_get_object();
$pathnoder = custom_pathnoder();

$group_id = $pathnoder[3];


$query = db_select('node');
 $query->condition('nid', '$group_id', '=')
              ->fields('type');
$og_type = $query->execute();



if ($og_type) {
if ($og_type == 'square_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => square) );
}

elseif ($og_type == 'west_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => west) );
}
elseif ($og_type == 'east_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => east) );
}
elseif ($og_type == 'circle_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => circle) );
}
elseif ($og_type == 'north_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => north) );
}
elseif ($og_type == 'south_group')  {
$def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => south) );
}
}

if (isset($def_value)) {
  return $def_value;
}
else {
  return array(0 => array('value' => null));
}
}
```

@Shawn Conn

I changed the code to reflect the suggestions above but it's still not setting the value.  Can you see the reason?

```
def_value = array();
$pathnoder = array();

$pathnoder = check_plain(drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
$pathnoder = explode('/', $pathnoder);


$og_type = db_select('node','n') 
    ->fields('n', array('type'))
    ->condition('nid', arg(3), '=')
    ->execute()->fetchField();

switch ($og_type) {
    case square_group:
         $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => square) );
         break;
    case west_group:
         $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => west) );
         break;
    case east_group:
       $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => east) );
       break;
    case circle_group:
       $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => circle) );
       break;
    case north_group:
       $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => north) );
       break;
    case south_group:
       $def_value = array( 0 => array('value' => south) );
       break;
}         
if (isset($def_value)) {
  return $def_value;
}
else {
  return array(0 => array('value' => null));
}
```

Comment: If you don't have it in your development environment. Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use the `dpm()` to investigate the values of `$og_type` & `arg(3)`. That should clue you off to where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this a little more convoluted than it needs be; the core [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function can parse out the path and get the 4th element; the query is also broke (`condition()` is passed a string literal instead of variable & it's missing aliasing argument); lastly you could help readability with a switch control.

```
  //fields() needs an alias argument $group_id can be pulled from arg()
  $og_type = db_select('node','n') 
    ->fields('n', array('type'))
    ->condition('nid', arg(3), '=')
    ->execute()->fetchField();
```